# How can I mock a sub in another module?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I am having troubles mocking a subroutine in another module than where I am running the tests.

I have my tests in a file called ParserTests.pl. I am trying to test a subroutine (parse) in a module LogParser.pm

```
sub parse {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $rr = $self->getRR;
    while(1) {
        my $result = $self->parseCommitSet();
        if ($result eq 2) {
            last;
        }
        my $printStatus = $self->printOut($result);
        if (!$printStatus) {
            say "Problem occurred with writing to output";
            return 0;
        }
        $self->setRR(ReportRecord->new());
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I am trying to mock printOut so that it always returns true. What I am trying to do is this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use v5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More 'no_plan';
use Test::MockObject;
use LogParser;
{other tests…}
my $mock = Test::MockObject->new();
$mock->set_true('LogParser::printOut');
my $test100FH = getTestFH($test100SetsNoPrev);
$logParser = LogParser->new($test100FH);
is($logParser->parse, 1, "im ok?");
close $test100FH;
```

But this test is failing. Can you tell me why and point me in the right path to get it working correctly for when I test parse()? I read up on a bunch of documentation but something like this is still a bit unclear.

The error is

```
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at /Users/achu/Documents/workspace/Perl_Script/LogParser.pm line 241, <$fh> line 8371.
# Looks like your test exited with 25 just after 91.
```

That line (line 241) is inside the printOut subroutine though which means that it's not mocking that subroutine like I wanted it to. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Test::MockModule`](http://search.cpan.org/~simonflk/Test-MockModule-0.05/lib/Test/MockModule.pm) is probably better suited to this;

```
my $module = Test::MockModule->new('LogParser');
$module->mock( printOut => sub { return 1 } );
```

This will cause `LogParser` to use your mocked version until `$module` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 5):

`Test::MockObject` does not quite do what you want.  It is good for supplying a minimally-implemented stub.  But for making an instance of the class under test and selectively overriding its methods, you want [`Test::MockObject::Extends`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test%3a%3aMockObject%3a%3aExtends).

`TMOE` takes an instance and then lets you change what some of its methods do.  In your example, you can use it to write the test thus:

```
use Test::MockObject::Extends;

my $test100FH = getTestFH($test100SetsNoPrev);
$logParser = Test::MockObject::Extends->new(
    LogParser->new($test100FH);
);
$logParser->set_true('printOut');

is($logParser->parse, 1, "im ok?");

close $test100FH;
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the error message, but what you've defined is an object called $mock that contains a 'printout' method.  But you're calling printout() on $logparser.

The point of MockObject is to create a very bare object, with a few methods so you can test other pieces of code in a algorithm that relies on an external object.  For example, you could mock a database handle so that calling $dbh->fetchStuff() always returns on static row, so that you can test the code that consumes the row.

So without more context, I can't tell the possibilities for just creating a stub for printOut() so that parse knows about it.

That being said, I also don't understand the desire to have a test for the return value of the stubbed method.

Comment: Indeed! mocking a method and then testing that it behaves as mockes is ... odd.

Comment: Apologies, I updated the test and added in the error code to show what kind of problem I'm actually trying to solve.

Comment: Why are you even trying to stub printOut() in the first place?

Comment: It does a lot of file io stuff that I dont want to deal with for testing parse currently.

Comment: At which point you might be better off coming up with a way to divert printOut() to /dev/null, or abstract printout() into a Logger object. Then you can mock the logger object via dependency injection (passing the logger into the constructor)

Comment: Ok, I think I could probably make something like that. Is there any way I could do it with how I have it now though?

Comment: There are way you could manipulate the symbol table, or you could just let the output happen.

Answer (score -1):

Please read the documentation for [Test::MockObject](https://metacpan.org/module/CHROMATIC/Test-MockObject-1.20120301/lib/Test/MockObject.pm) and try to understand how it works.

You are doing only the first half of what is actually required: You are creating a mock object. But this will not magically end up in your LogParser.

What `Test::MockObject` gives you is an object that behaves just like the object you want to mock. Of course, somebody or something still has to use that object. And this will have to be the code you are trying to test.

Comment: I updated the test to call parse and see if it will use the mocked object but the error shows that its still stepping into the printOut subroutine. Im not quite sure how to get it to use the mocked object. Im just not doing it right but I cant seem to figure out what is the correct way to do it.